# What is the replacement for `publishReplay(1).refCount()` in RxJS version 7.4.0

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am learning RxJS and Angular. The below code is a simplified version of rxjs-chat from the book ‘ng-book2-book-angular-11-r77.pdf’.
It’s a simple Angular service class.
This is what I am trying to do:

1. Call from outside `addMessage(1)` method
2. From that method I push value `"1"` onto `newMessages` `Subject` using `newMessages.next()` method.
3. `newMessages` subscribes in turn to `updates`(`Subject`)
4. `updates` is using `pipe` member of `updates` to `map` passed `message` into concatenated array of numbers (`messages`) and returns the concatenated array (the initial value of concatenated array is kept in `const initialMessages`).
5. The result is stored into the `messages`(`Observable`).
6. `pipe` method also calls `share` operator so the `messages` Observable can update Observable `newNumbers` object (at least that what I thought it would do)
7. That where my problem is  - the `newNumbers` are not updated. I thought that the `this.newNumbers = this.messages...` will execute because of my `share` operator is called. (Similar code in the mentioned above book works but they are using deprecated methods `publishReplay(1).refCount()` instead of my `share` operator. Could someone point me in the right direction - below is the code:

```js
const initialMessages: number[] = [];

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessagesService {
  // `newNumbers` is a observable that contains the most up to date list of numbers
  newNumbers: Observable<{ [key: string]: number }>;

  newMessages: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  // `messages` is a stream that emits an array of the most up to date numbers
  messages: Observable<number[]>;

  updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    this.messages = this.updates
      // watch the updates and accumulate operations on the messages
      .pipe(
        map((message) => {
          let retVal = initialMessages.concat(message);
          return retVal;
        }),
        share({
          connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
          resetOnError: false,
          resetOnComplete: false,
          resetOnRefCountZero: false,
        })
      );

    this.newMessages.subscribe(this.updates);

    this.newNumbers = this.messages.pipe(
      map((messages: number[]) => {
        const numbers: { [key: string]: number } = {};
        messages.map((n: number) => {
          numbers[n] = numbers[n] || n;
          console.log(n);
        });
        return numbers;
      })
    );

    this.messages.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));
  }

  addMessage(value: number): void {
    this.newMessages.next(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you subscribed to the `newNumbers` observable, what is the expected result?

Comment: If I subscribe to the `newNumbers' then they assignment `this.messages = this.updates...` is executed. Does it mean that if I don't subscribe to `newNumbers ` the code  `this.messages = this.updates...` gets compiled out as it is not referenced?

Comment: So it works as expected when subscribed to it?

Comment: Yep. So does the compiler removes the code above if it is not subscribed?

Comment: No, it's the default behavior of the `Observable`, it won't being executed until you subscribed to it: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

Comment: publishReplay is deprecated and will be removed in V8. (https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/publishReplay) . The docu points to the new share operator, of which shareReplay is a wrapper to give the count replayed.

Answer (score 0):

Although that still works in rxjs `7.4.0` it's deprecated and will be removed in version `8.0.0`.

This is the current suggested refactor from the rxjs team:

```
import { timer, share, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

// suggested refactor
const tick$ = timer(1_000).pipe(
  share({
    connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
    resetOnError: false,
    resetOnComplete: false,
    resetOnRefCountZero: false
  })
);
```

Source: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/multicasting#publishreplay

I see that it might not be working for your case and there's another thread going on here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6452
Which suggests the migration documentation might be misleading. So in your case this might work better:

```
const tick$ = timer(1_000).pipe(
  (source$) => {
    const subject = new ReplaySubject(1);

    return source$.pipe(
      share({
        connector: () => subject,
        resetOnError: false,
        resetOnComplete: false,
        resetOnRefCountZero: true,
      }),
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Operators publishReplay(1) + refCount() are equals to shareReplay(1)